# Comments/Review pane alternates between expanded and collapsed view (picture)

Tags: microsoft-word, display-settings, comments, review

Within the same Word file, the comments/review pane is displaying in one of two ways: either collapsed or expanded.

Within a page, the display is the same, but across pages, the displays are different. Further, the displays are random. For example, pages 1, 2, 7, 10 might display one way, while the other pages display the other (there is no discernible pattern).

[image: Heres a screenshot; the expanded view on the right is the one I want]

Notice also that in the collapsed view, only author initials appear, but in the expanded view there is a purple icon to the left of the author initials.

I've tried the following:

- increasing and decreasing the width of the pane
- saving with a new file name
- deleting normal.dotm (i.e., to create a fresh one with factory settings)
- copying all of the content to a new file except for the final paragraph marker.
- inserting additional page breaks (in case the problem was related to lengthy comments)

Environment: Windows 10 running Office Pro Plus 2019

Comment: When there are **too many** comments to fit in sidebar, the comments would be collapsed. Try to inset the Page Break, check whether the comments expanded. When the comments are not too long, you could also `click the small icon at the bottom-right of the Tracking group in Review tab > Advanced Options > balloons, increase the Preferred Width`.

Comment: @Emily - The original post notes that I tried page breaks and expanding balloon width. I tried again just now. Failure repeats itself. Other suggestions always welcome.